# How do I select all of the records in a linked server that have a non-null value for a specific column into a local database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a linked server which contains many tables. Some of those tables contain a certain column called exampleColumn. I would like to select all of the records in the linked server which have a non-null value for the exampleColumn. (ignoring all tables which do not have this column and all records which have a null value for this column) I would like to select the entire row including all of the other columns if the exampleColumn has a value.

Additionally, I would like to create the tables and columns in my local server to house the selected data with the same names and datatypes as they are in the linked server (without creating tables which will have no records brought over)

I have found many resources online which describe how to select into from different databases based on a specific value, but I have not found any which checks all tables instead of just one. I also am unable to find anything on dynamically creating tables/columns based on the source of the select.

Comment: You can use SELECT INTO to create the table with a select statement. You would need to look at sys.tables and sys.columns to know which tables have a columns with a specific name. Then use dynamic sql and a where clause.

Comment: @SeanLange The challenge is dynamically creating the tables which I am selecting into. As mentioned in my question. Do you know how to do this? Can you show me?

Comment: Do you need to create permanent tables to select into, or can you use TEMP tables to hold and view the data until you know what data you'll be inserting? If you can make use of temp tables just while you're pulling the data across the linked server, you can use SELECT... INTO #TEMP FROM...

Comment: @thermos I have the permissions to create temp tables, but the end result should be the creation of permanent tables which contain only records that have a non-null value for that exampleColumn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally sure what you want here as there is not much in the way of details but pretty sure you can do something like this. This will generate all the insert statements you need to run. You could either stick this into a variable and execute it via dynamic sql or just copy and paste to run this. Not really sure where the linked server is here in relation to what you are running your query either.

```
declare @ColumnName sysname = 'exampleColumn'

select 'select * into ' + quotename(object_name(object_id)) + ' from [LinkServer].[Database].[Schema].' + quotename(object_name(object_id)) + ' where ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + ' is not null;'
from sys.columns
where name = @ColumnName
```

--EDIT--

To only create local tables for remote tables that have at least one row where your column is not null simply add an EXISTS before the select. Like this.

```
select 'IF EXISTS(select * from [LinkServer].[Database].[Schema].' + quotename(object_name(object_id)) + ' where ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + ' is not null) select * into ' + quotename(object_name(object_id)) + ' from [LinkServer].[Database].[Schema].' + quotename(object_name(object_id)) + ' where ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + ' is not null;'
from sys.columns
where name = @ColumnName
```

Comment: This works for selecting from all tables. Thank you very much. For the second part of my question, do you know how to create a table and the columns needed as they are in the linked server to house the selected data? For example, if LinkedServer..."exampleTable" has the exampleColumn column and 20 records which have a non-null value for it, how can i create this table in my local database with the same columns that the linked server table has? If my linked server has 50 tables, but only 20 of them have records with a nonnull value for that column, then I only want 20 tables created locally.

Comment: Forgive me for my inexperience here but does this actually generate a sql statement that creates a table? It looks like it checks to see if it exists and then selects into it. I need to create the table if it does not exist, using the metadata from the table in the linked server.

Comment: Select INTO creates the target table. You can't use that syntax if the table exists. You can read about the INTO clause in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Just figured it out. You had '' from [LinkServer].[Database].[Schema].' when I really needed ' from [LinkServer].[Database].dbo.' This generated a sql statement that did exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad that helped. Just so know dbo is the schema, it is just the default schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
if exists (select 1 from [linkedserver].[db].[schema].[tableX]) begin

select *
into [schema].[tableX]
from [linkedserver].[db].[schema].[tableX]

end;
```